# I am trying to configure my app by using EXPO's example from the docs, while it shows syntax error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I am trying to use this code which found on expo documentation. I've already included images and fonts that I a musing while it shows strange error on the line of ionicons font like expected , . While its correct. I can't find what is wrong?

```
function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map(image => {
    if (typeof image === 'string') {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     isReady: false,
      store: configureStore(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false })),
      mainApplication: false,
    };
  }


  async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    const imageAssets = cacheImages([
     require("./assets/icons/app.png"),
      require("./assets/icons/loading.png"),
      require("./img/img1.jpg"),
      require("./img/img2.jpg"),
      require("./img/img3.jpg"),

    ]);

    const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
     Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
        Arial: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
        Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
        Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),]);

    await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
  }

 render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      );
    }
else {
    return (
      return  <Provider store={this.state.store}>
      <Root>
            <Nav/>
            </Root>
</Provider>;
    );
  }
}
```

What is wrong on this code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you add the exact error to your question?

Comment: syntax error expectec '; ' on the line 
Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),

Answer (score 0):

These steps should help you resolve your problem:

1. Check your package.json for `react-native-vector-icons` as dependency and remove it if it exists
2. Run `npm install @expo/vector-icons --save`
3. Remove your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again